# How to submit a form to a different server without database details

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am new to stackoverflow community.I have a little issue
Here is a webpage http://ebook.autocab.net/4431 and this page has a username and password
Here is a public version of this page http://ebook.autocab.net/guest/4431
The problem with this page is that it is very basic in layout and the company i bought it off won't change its layout and it runs on their servers. Basically its a taxi booking form and when you submit the form it creates a new taxi journey on a software i run in my office.
I want to create a new form on my own website according to my needs but when visitors submit that form on my domain it should get submitted to ebook.autocab.net so that booking appears on my software in my office.is there anyway to save these files as mentioned above.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Use curl to make a post request to the other server.

Comment: Have you tried just getting the source of the page (from view source) and putting it on your browser with the full URL in the form action?

Comment: I'd suggest that you hire a freelancer who will do this for you. It doesn't seem you're a programmer, and someone with mid-range knowledge will do this within 1 day of work so it won't be too expensive.

Comment: This could be against their TOS. You should check that out first.

Comment: You can use jquery ajax with url as the server domain name or use cURL.

Answer (score 2):

Copy their form HTML and relevant javascript to your site. When it comes to the action of the form change it from a relative url if they have one to an absolute url.

eg.

`<form action="book_taxi" ...>` to `<form action="https://ebook.autocab.net/book_taxi" ...>`

If you are having issues with cross domain policies post it to a php script on your server and forward it on through a curl request